# How can I scrape Songs Title from this request that I have collected using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://gaana.com/playlist/gaana-dj-hindi-top-50-1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find("div", {"class": "s_c"})
print(result.class)
```

From the above code, I am able to scrape this data

https://www.pastiebin.com/5f08080b8db82

Now I would like to scrape only the title of the songs and then make a list out of them like the below:

1. Meri Aashiqui
2. Genda Phool

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Have you attempted anything to get the titles? If yes, share the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://gaana.com/playlist/gaana-dj-hindi-top-50-1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find("div", {"class": "s_c"})
#print(result)
div = result.find_all('div', class_='track_npqitemdetail')
name_list = []
for x in div:
    span = x.find('span').text
    name_list.append(span)

print(name_list)
```

this code will return all song name in `name_list` list.